# The Canvas .fillText method doesn't seem to work on the iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, canvas

It does show text, but in the completely wrong place (not even on the Canvas element itself!), and in the wrong color (always black). Has anyone had experience with this or gotten it working?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Works on normal safari. Did you get it working in the end?

Comment: Never got it to work. I ended up assuming the iPad canvas impl is simply incomplete.

Comment: Same problem here. I use iOS 5.1.1. and iPad 3, the filltext method maxWidth parameter doesn't work for me. The text has same with, even if I give it to absurdicaly minimal value(like 5.0 or 10.0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was broken in iOS before 4.0.

It seems to work fine in iOS 4.0 and later.